# Google Blogger: See how many subscriptions?

Tags: blogger

If you have a blog with Google Blogger, is there any way to see how many people are subscribed to it?  In the blogger dashboard there's a lot of statistics, but I don't see any for subscriptions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to track subscriptions is through [Google Feedburner](http://feedburner.com), which redirects your RSS feed. The only downside is that if you're transmitting your feed elsewhere, say a tool that posts to your Twitter or Yahoo Pipes, those bots/scripts will show up as subscribers and will skew the results slightly.

Comment: I don't think I understand.  How does Feedburner work??  How will this accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Feedburner redirects your feeds and counts subscribers. You could've found that out if you carefully read the 10 sentences on the login page & clicked [Learn more](http://support.google.com/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79408). Blogger doesn'tr track subscribers otherwise.

Comment: Perfect, I'll give that a shot.  Thanks!